# How do you compute the expected value of an infinite distribution? (particularly in python)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I was trying to compute the expected value of a distribution (assume I know the parameters or I can estimate them) but it might be a distribution over a sample space that is infinite. Is there a library (for example in python, numpy or something) that is able to compute such an expected value with reasonable speed and accuracy?

For an arbitrary distribution it seemed hard, but the only thoughts I had was, if it was normally, then we can approximate this by adding small enough chunks in cap where the probability is highly concentrated or something...but I wanted to do something less ad-hoc and more established, since I am sure I am not the first one to try to compute an expected value in a computer.

Comment: How are you even going to *represent* an infinite distribution? The answer will depend on the representation.

Comment: Just because something is infinite and there is not an obvious way to represent it, it doesn't mean you can't compute useful stuff out of it. Say for example in machine learning, sometimes u want infinite feature vector of polynomials, if u wanted that, u wouldn't be able to represent it in a computer as a vector, but u can still compute useful stuff, like predictions and stuff by using the radial basis kernel. So I am not sure if representing is even important as sometimes u don't need to.

Comment: You need *some* sort of representation. If your representation is an array of samples of the probability density function, with anything past the bounds of the array deemed negligible, then you just use techniques for a bounded distribution. If your representation is "it's a normal distribution with these specific parameters", you pull out the parameter representing the mean. If your representation is a description of a procedure to sample from the distribution, perhaps you generate a bunch of samples and average them.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I am not suggesting the mathematical object I am trying to compute can come out of nowhere without specifying anything for the computer. The only thing I am saying is, just because the sample space is infinite or if the object I have has a conceptually infinite representation, it does not mean that we have to use the obvious (by obvious I mean the infinite) representation to compute anything from it. Like I said before, there are vectors that can have a conceptual infinite size and we can still compute really easily finite things out of them.

Comment: Maybe in this case, its not the case there is a smart way of doing computing the expected value, but just saying its infinite so you can't do anything, is not really the answer I was looking for. Of course I know it depends on how I do stuff, If I decide to just chop of a portion of the sample space and compute my value, it might be a valid thing to do, but it has it costs and limitation, and its fine if it does, I'm just sure I am not the first one trying to compute numerically a expected value from a infinite sample space, so there must be something out there.

Comment: I'm not saying "it's infinite so you can't do anything". I'm asking what representation you're using. What information does it store? What does it lose? What can or can't be represented? What tradeoffs does it make to keep memory usage finite?

Comment: Note that I did propose a number of ways an infinite distribution might be represented, and a number of associated ways to compute expected value. I'm not saying this is impossible; I'm saying that the representation is important.

Comment: I guess we misunderstood each other, but I do say I agree, representation are always important. I think it depends on the distribution, some distributions have a finite number of parameters and those encode the Probability of a certain event from happening. Like if we tried to do the normal, then the mean and the variance. I guess that is one problem with my question is that, I am trying to not leave out any distribution by being too specific. But, answer that are limit the scope can still be useful.

Comment: Though, thats why I was asking if maybe there was a library that did this or something. Not sure if I made it more clear or more confusing... hope not more confusing. :)

Answer (score 2):

Having a probability space with infinite support is not uncommon.

The normal or t distribution have support over the real line, the Poisson distribution is over all positive integers.

The distribution in `scipy.stats` implement an `expect` method, which in the continuous case just uses `scipy.integrate.quad`, and in the discrete case uses expanding summation with some heuristic stopping criterion.

This works quite well with well behaved functions but can run into problems in some cases, like shifted support of the function or fat tails.

variance of standard normal:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> stats.norm.expect(lambda x: x**2)
1.000000000000001
```

variance of Poisson:

```
>>> stats.poisson.expect(lambda x: (x - 5)**2, args=(5,))
4.9999999999999973
```